# discord.js V12 Send message to each guild owner from message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to send message to each owner of each guild of my bot.

To do that I have try this :

```js
/**
 * @param {import('discord.js').Message} message
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
module.exports = async (message) => {
    message.client.guilds.map((guild) =>{
        message.client.users.fetch(guild.owner.id).then(u =>{
            u.send('my awesome custom message')
        })
    })
}
```

But with this code I have this error :

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.client.guilds.map is not a function`

but when I console.logs `message.client.guilds` I have an array of the guild... So I don't really know how I can parkour each guilds. Also in my bot struct, I can access to `client` by another that this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Discord.js v12, you need to add the `cache` property.
So it would be `message.client.guilds.cache.map(...)`

This amends your code to:

```js
/**
 * @param {import('discord.js').Message} message
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
module.exports = async (message) => {
    message.client.guilds.cache.map((guild) =>{
        message.client.users.fetch(guild.owner).then(u =>{
            u.send('my awesome custom message')
        })
    })
}
```